# guard let foo = foo VS guard foo != nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, guard

I don't understand the concept of making a useless constant if the task is only to unwrap the value:

```
guard let foo = foo else { return }
```

vs

```
guard foo != nil else { return }
```

What is the difference between these statements? And what is the reason to not use the latter?

Here is some example of using guard let:

```
var array: [String] = ["pineapple", "potato", "corn"]

guard let lastElement = array.last, lastElement == "corn" else { return false }
```

And not using let:

```
guard array.last == "corn" else { return false }
```

Can't I just go with the second approach as more clean, simple and probably more memory efficient?

Comment: Your question before the edit made more sense -- with your edit, `array` cannot be `nil` as it's defined as `[String]` and `array.last` would fail without being `array?.last` if it were. Probably better to roll back to the original question.

Comment: Please post your actual code. `array != nil` ??? `last` is optional but your `array` is not

Comment: `guard foo != nil else { return }` would be useful in situations where you don't want to use the value of `foo`, but where the modifications of workflow would otherwise be reliant on it's state been set

Answer (score 7):

With your first example, `foo` becomes a non-Optional. So, you can do this:

```
guard let foo = foo else { return }
foo.doMethod()
```

Whereas without the optional binding, you'd still have an Optional:

```
guard foo != nil else { return }
foo?.doMethod()
```

There are plenty of times when having a non-Optional value is easier to deal with, including being able to avoid force unwrapping with `!`, so there's lots of practicality to the first code sample.

In terms of the second version, you could use it where you want to do a `nil` check but may not actually use the value in the scope in which you're checking it.

---

In your example with the array of type `[String]`, yes, you can do your second comparison without the optional binding to check to see if there's a `last` element:

```
guard array.last == "corn" else { return false }
```

You are correct that it is cleaner this way. It is extremely unlikely that it would be more "memory efficient" as you speculated, though, as the compiler would likely optimize away the temporary optional binding.

Comment: One other benefit to the non-`Optional` local binding of `foo` over just checking `!= nil`: if `foo` otherwise references an `Optional` property, it's possible for the property to be assigned a `nil` value even after the `guard` passes. Since you'd be looking up the value of `foo` with every access, this might lead to surprising behavior; whereas with the local binding, even if the property changes, your local variable won't.

Comment: Yes — good addition!

Comment: My argument here is that 'if let' concept is being used by default in almost every possible situation, even when you're 100% sure there won't be any surprising behavior.